# How can I get number just under a number in equation?

Tags: markdown, equation, quarto

[image: Quarto equation]

How can I get numbers under the numbers in Quarto?

I have this so far:

```
\hat{y}_{1t}=-0.980+6.903*10^{-6}JanAprTNLoad_{t,}
```

I cannot find any reference to get the numbers under the numbers in the equations.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Try with `\underset{}{}` where contents in first bracket is put under the contents in second bracket.

```
---
title: "Equations"
format: 
  html: default
  pdf: default
---

$$
\begin{aligned}
\hat{y}_{1t} &= \underset{(0.405)}{-0.980} + \underset{(1.069\times10^{-6}) }{6.903\times10^{-6}}JanAprTNLoad_{t,} \\
\hat{y}_{2t} &= \underset{(0.426)}{-0.217} +  \underset{(1.360\times10^{-6}) }{5.596\times10^{-6}}JanMayTNLoad_{t,}
\end{aligned}
$$
```

---

[image: equation with underset]

---